# Elixir Release does not output log to file

Tags: logging, elixir

I use `{:exrm, "~> 0.19.9"}` to create Elixir project `deployagent` release file(`MIX_ENV=dev mix compile && MIX_ENV=dev mix release`)  and load it using `rel/deployagent/bin/deployagent console` command.

I want to output some log to file so i add `{:logger_file_backend, "~> 0.0.6"}` to my `mix.exs` file.

The configuration I did in `conf/dev.exs` is like below:

```
config :logger,
backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}]

config :logger, :error_log,
  path: "log/error.log",
  level: :error,
  format: "$time [$level] $message\n"
```

I also add `:logger_file_backend` to the `application` part of `mix.exs` file . `[applications: [:logger, :logger_file_backend, :amqp, :ssh, :poison]`

The thing that confused me is when i load the app using **`$ iex -S mix` and it just worked fine** , `Logger.error message` will output the `message` to file `log/error.log`. **But when I use `rel/deployagent/bin/deployagent console` , it does not output the `message` to file `log/error.log`**

So can someone tell me what's **the difference between `iex -S mix` and `rel/deployagent/bin/deployagent console`**

---

#### Solved

I did not look at the right place to find the log.

When using `iex -S mix`, the log file is in `deployagent/log/error.log`,

When I created the release, the log is in **`deployagent/rel/deployagent/log/error.log`**

Comment: I'm not experienced with exrm, but 0.19.9 seems to be quite an old version. Hex has version 1.0.0-rc8 available, maybe that will solve it?

https://hex.pm/packages/exrm

Comment: That's a good suggestion Sasha.  I'd see if the problem occurs with 1.0.0-rc8 as well.  If it still does then add that to your question.

Comment: When I want to add my self made file backend, it turned out that I didn't look at the right place to find the log.  I just updated the post. thank you guys .