# How to log to file using logger_file_backend with the phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm presently building out an API using the phoenix framework v1.3 rc1 and everything works as intended on my local dev environment, but when I pushed the changes to a production box to test the API the phx app is returning 500 Internal Server Error. I'm trying to setup logging for the dev / prod environments using `logger_file_backend` by following [the instructions](https://github.com/onkel-dirtus/logger_file_backend/blob/master/README.md) on the github page, but I'm not seeing any log files being generated in the dev or prod environments.

**config.exs**

```
# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
  backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}]
  # format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  # metadata: [:request_id]

# configuration for the {LoggerFileBackend, :error_log} backend
config :logger, :error_log,
  path: "/home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api/error.log",
  level: :error
```

**prod.exs**

```
# Do not print debug messages in production
# config :logger, level: :info
config :logger, format: "[$level] $message\n",
  backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}, :console]

config :logger, :error_log,
  path: "/home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api/error.log",
  level: :error
```

**dev.exs**

```
# Do not include metadata nor timestamps in development logs
config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n",
  backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}, :console]

config :logger, :error_log,
  path: "/opt/elixir/kegcopr_api/log/error.log",
  level: :debug
```

Comment: If you run the app in console mode on the production server, you will see the error message. For example, if your using exrm or distillery, run it as `bin/my_app console`.

Comment: @StevePallen thanks for the suggestion, but I'm deploying this app using `gatling` which apparently does not play nice with the command you suggested.

Comment: How are you calling Logger.debug in your code?

Comment: I've never used gatling, but I don't know how anyone can work with a production server without being able to run the app in console mode. This is the first thing I do when I'm have problems with a production app.

Comment: I just looked at the gatling docs. It's just a set of tools to create a release with Distillery and release it. ssh into your box and got to the root directory of your app. then run `bin/my_app stop` and then `bin/my_app console`. You should then see the error messages in the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this config:

```
config :logger, 
  backends: [:console, {LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}],
  format: "[$level] $message\n"

config :logger, :error_log, 
  path: "/tmp/info.log",
  level: :debug
```

Its working for me.

```
iex(1)> require Logger
Logger
iex(2)> Logger.debug "more here"
:ok
iex(3)>
21:39:58.608 [debug] more here

$ tail -f /tmp/info.log
21:34:29.756 [info] testing..
21:38:23.380 [debug] test me
21:39:58.608 [debug] more here
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  The API appears to be working now.  However when I send malformed JSON response to the API, I don't see the log file being created in `/tmp` on the production box.  Let me check to see if dev is different.

Comment: Yeah the log file isn't being created on the dev box either :/

Comment: @Chris any luck on this? Im having the same issue

Comment: Haven't messed with in quite some time, so that'd be a no.

Comment: @SheshankKodam Can you provide an example on how to reproduce ur issue please.

Comment: @Chris You might not need this but posted a solution which worked for me below for someone who comes across this issue

Comment: @StevePallen I got the solution. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

How to change the format of the logging? I would like to add `date` before `time` in the log.

I have the added `$date` to the `:format` in the configuration but the date does not show up in logging.

```
# tell logger to load a LoggerFileBackend processes
config :logger,
    backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :hutt}],
    format: "$date $time $metadata[$level] $message\n"

# configuration for the {LoggerFileBackend, :hutt} backend
config :logger, :hutt,
       path: "log/hutt.log",
       level: :info

iex(1)> require Logger
Logger
iex(2)> Logger.info("hello")
:ok
tail -f log/hutt.log
12:33:13.550 [info] Running HuttWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:5000
12:36:28.669 [info] hello
```

**ANSWER**

Adding format to the stanza worked

```
config :logger, :hutt,
       format: "$date $time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
       path: "log/hutt.log",
       level: :info
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. Check logs in the right location. See [Elixir Release does not output log to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500748/elixir-release-does-not-output-log-to-file) for more information.
2. In my case, I was running the command `MIX_ENV=test mix release --env=prod` and realised that the output config is not outputting to console or file. I updated the `config/test.exs` with following changes mentioned below and [here](https://github.com/onkel-dirtus/logger_file_backend/issues/52)

   `config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"`